# How to unhide one console app from another app?

Tags: c#, windows

I've got an app that runs in background (console app is hidden). I want to make, that if user tries to open more than one instance of this app (clicks on *.exe file), the new one will be closed and the currently running one will be shown.

This is what I've tried:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    const int SW_SHOW = 5;


bool moreThanOne = false;
        string processName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] arr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
        Console.WriteLine("Looking for: " + processName);
        foreach (var a in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.ProcessName);
            if (a.ProcessName == processName)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
                if (moreThanOne)
                {
                    IntPtr handle = a.MainWindowHandle;
                    ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
                    Console.WriteLine("close!!!!1111");

                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    moreThanOne = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

It currently doesn't work and I have no idea why. Process is always found properly, but there is some problem with "unhiding" previously opened app. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is returning ShowWindow after you call it? The call looks good.

Comment: Also note the that nCmdShow value is ignored in the first call to ShowWindow if the program that launched the application specifies startup information in the structure. In this case, ShowWindow uses the information specified in the STARTUPINFO structure to show the window. On subsequent calls, the application must call ShowWindow with nCmdShow set to SW_SHOWDEFAULT to use the startup information provided by the program that launched the application. This behavior is designed for the following situations:

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 I've updated code in question

Comment: replace this line  ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW); with this MessageBox.Show(ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW).ToString()); and run the program again and let me know what value is it returning (1 or 0)

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 what is "MessageBox"? Is it available in console applications?

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Try Console.WriteLine(ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW).ToString());

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 the result is "True"

Comment: If the window was previously visible, the return value is nonzero. That's what the documentation says. Could it be that the application is running on another user's session? Or you are the one launching the application?

Comment: I know that this must sound weird but you can also try duplicating the ShowWindow line and see if that works.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 so, app runs on my user's session (I'm opening it, hide, and then open another instance to see if it works). App is being hidden the same way I try to unhide it.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 and no, doubling the ShowWindow line doesn't work ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98736/discussion-between-programmerv5-and-ludwik11).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that user launch you application twice is better idea use Mutex instead of checking process list (image if another user launch your application again and the first has not the privilege to see it).

You Main become like that (using winform)

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionHandler);

            using (new SingleGlobalInstance(TIMEOUT_START))
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                _mainProgram = new frmMainProgram();

                ApplicationContext appCtx = new ApplicationContext(_mainProgram);
                Application.Run(appCtx);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception unhandled)
        {
            Program.UnhandledExceptionHandler(null, (new UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(unhandled, true)));
        }
    }
```

An then the object that hide the Mutex logic

```
public class SingleGlobalInstance : IDisposable
{
    public bool hasHandle = false;
    Mutex mutex;

    private void InitMutex()
    {
        string appGuid = ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false).GetValue(0)).Value.ToString();
        string mutexId = string.Format("Global\\{{{0}}}", appGuid);
        mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexId);

        var allowEveryoneRule = new MutexAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
        var securitySettings = new MutexSecurity();
        securitySettings.AddAccessRule(allowEveryoneRule);
        mutex.SetAccessControl(securitySettings);
    }

    public SingleGlobalInstance(int timeOut)
    {
        InitMutex();
        try
        {
            if (timeOut < 0)
                hasHandle = mutex.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite, false);
            else
                hasHandle = mutex.WaitOne(timeOut, false);

            if (hasHandle == false)
                throw new TimeoutException("Timeout waiting for exclusive access on SingleInstance");
        }
        catch (AbandonedMutexException)
        {
            hasHandle = true;
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (mutex != null)
        {
            if (hasHandle)
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            mutex.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to get timeout you could throw special exception here and unhide hidden application befor exiting (from the application that get timeout)